# How do I keep raycast relative to the object its bound to?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a car game and I would like to use raycast to detect other obstacles and do stuff if the ray hits.
The problem is after the car does a 90 degree turn the raycast move in a way I did not intend them to, like this: [image: this is how it looks when I first draw the rays]

But when I rotate the car by 90 degrees it looks like this:

[image: rotated by 90]

I'd like the rays to remain as they are in the first image regardless of the rotation of the car.

Here is the code to cast the rays and to draw them:

```
 private void OnDrawGizmos()
{
    sensorStartPosition1 = transform.position + new Vector3(1f, 0.6f, 0f);
    sensorStartPosition2 = transform.position + new Vector3(-1f, 0.6f, 0f);
    Gizmos.DrawRay(sensorStartPosition1, transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.right) * 3.5f);
    Gizmos.DrawRay(sensorStartPosition2, transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.left) * 3.5f);
}

 private void RunSensors()
{
    RaycastHit hit1;
    sensorStartPosition1 = transform.position + new Vector3(1f, 0.6f, 0);
    //dTS = detect traffic signs
    Ray dTS = new Ray(sensorStartPosition1, transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.right));

    if(Physics.Raycast(dTS, out hit1, sensorLen ))
    {

    }
    Debug.DrawRay(sensorStartPosition1, transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.right) * 3.5f);

    RaycastHit hit2;
    sensorStartPosition2 = transform.position + new Vector3(-1f, 0.6f, 0);
    // dLIT1 = detect left incoming traffic
    Ray dLIT1 = new Ray(sensorStartPosition2, transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.left));
    if(Physics.Raycast(dLIT1, out hit2, sensorLen))
    {

    }
    Debug.DrawRay(sensorStartPosition1, transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.left) * 3.5f);
}
```

what am I doing wrong?.. thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You calculate the two start positions with an offset along the global world space X axis regardless of the rotation in

```
sensorStartPosition1 = transform.position + new Vector3(1f, 0.6f, 0f);

//...

sensorStartPosition2 = transform.position + new Vector3(-1f, 0.6f, 0f);
```

instead rather calculate them like

```
sensorStartPosition1 = transform.position + transform.right * 1f + transform.up * 0.6f;

//...

sensorStartPosition2 = transform.position + transform.right * -1f + transform.up * 0.6f;
```

Or simply

```
sensorStartPosition1 = transform.position + transform.rotation * new Vector3(1f, 0.6f, 0f);

//...

sensorStartPosition2 = transform.position + transform.rotation * new Vector3(-1f, 0.6f, 0f);
```

---

Btw instead of

```
transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.right)
transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.left)
```

you can also simply use

```
transform.right
-transform.right
```

Comment: ah I understand now.. new vector3 is a relative to global positioning whereas operations on members of the transform are relative to the object the script is attached to.. thank you

Comment: `transform.right` basically equals `transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.right)` .. the other one multiplies by the rotation of your object so it basically takes the new vector but rotates it according to the object's orientation